# Spring - распределенное приложение

Tags: java, spring

Добрый день, господа! У меня к вам скорее вопрос о возможностях, чем о какой то конкретике.
Есть задумка: одна rest-варка со spring security; n-ное количество ear архивов с логикой приложения.Все это деплоиться на jboss.
Проблемы:
1 Спринг не стартует в ear, ему подавай war, зарегистрировать disptacherServlet и пр.
2 Юзать ejb для подключения сервисов из ear - зачем тогда спринг вообще?
3 Eсли вместо ear делать war и связывать варки через rmi RmiServiceExporter, так и порты могут закончиться =), и вообще не выглядит так себе.

Возможно ли (и есть ли смысл) сделать распределенное приложение на Spring Framework? Наведите на best practice, подскажите правильное архитектурное решение, или может спринг на такие подвиги не способен(или я не способен его сподвигнуть)? Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Уточните, Вы хотите разнести логику приложения на разные приложения (в одном приложении security, в другом - бизнес-логика), или вам нужно отказоустойчивое решение (задублированы несколько экземпляров приложения)?

Comment: В принципе верно - в одном рест+security, в другом(других) бизнес-логика. Идея в том чтобы именно разнести логику по микросервисам. Вообще уже накопал интересное решение на базе спринг - spring-cloud, но мне интересны все возможности